# Getting both an individual value and a sum from a table in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Suppose after a query from a bigger dataset I have a table like this:

```
day   x   y
1     4   5
2     3   6
3     3   2
4     2   1
5     8   3
```

From that table I want to get the values of x and y from day 1 and the sums of x and y from all days into a new table. And how to have the results in a table with two rows instead of just one? Like this:

```
         x    y
day1     4    5
days1-5  20   17
```

Now the best I can do is this:

```sql
SELECT 
    SUM(x) AS allx, 
    SUM(y) AS ally, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 1 THEN x END) AS day1x, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN day = 1 THEN y END) AS day1y
FROM (
       ..
       ..
 )
```

I guess there is a more clever way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> BigQuery - Legacy SQL:

Using [comma style UNION ALL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#from)

```
SELECT 
  day, x, y 
FROM 
( SELECT 'day1' AS day, x, y 
  FROM YourTable
  WHERE day = 1 ),
( SELECT 
    CONCAT('day1-',STRING(COUNT(1))) AS day, 
    SUM(x) AS x, 
    SUM(y) AS y 
  FROM YourTable )
```

OR
Using [ROLLUP](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#groupbyrollup)

```
SELECT
  CONCAT('day_', IFNULL(STRING(day), 'all')) AS day, 
  x,
  y
FROM (
  SELECT 
    DAY, 
    SUM(x) AS x, 
    SUM(y) AS y 
  FROM YourTable
  GROUP BY ROLLUP(day)
)
WHERE IFNULL(day, 1) = 1
```

> BigQuery - Standard SQL:

*Don't forget to uncheck `Use Legacy SQL` checkbox under <kbd>Show Options</kbd>*

```
SELECT 
  'day1' AS day, 
  x, 
  y 
FROM YourTable 
WHERE day = 1 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  FORMAT('day1-%d', COUNT(1)) AS day, 
  SUM(x) AS x, 
  SUM(y) AS y 
FROM YourTable
```

Output from al  is as expected:

```
day     x   y    
day1    4   5    
day1-5  20  17
```